# How do I split my data set into matrix's using the first 70 as a training matrix, and 30 as a testing matrix?

Tags: r, matrix

I'm new to R so I'm not entirely sure how to do the following. I would like to split my data set into matrix's using the first 69 as a training matrix and the last 30 as a testing matrix.

I have this:

```
dim(iris)  # 99 5

#Sample Indexes
indexes = sample(1:nrow(iris), size=0.7*nrow(iris))

#Split data
train = iris[indexes,]
test = iris[-indexes,]

rm(indexes)

train.X <- matrix(train, nrow = 69, ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)

test.X <- matrix(test, nrow = 30, ncol = 5, byrow = FALSE, dimnames = NULL)
```

but the matrix is filled with 'Numeric,69 '

Comment: There should be `test = iris[-indexes,]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `as.matrix()` directly to convert a `data.frame()` into a matrix:

```
train.X <- as.matrix(iris[indexes, -5])
test.X <- as.matrix(iris[-indexes, -5])
```

but you might want to look into `?model.matrix` in order to convert a `data.frame` into a `matrix` for modelling purposes:

```
mat <- model.matrix(Species ~ -1 + ., data = iris)
train.X <- mat[indexes, ]
test.X <- mat[-indexes, ]
```

Comment: Thank you, this works like a charm. How would I go about doing the same 70/30 split but as vectors instead of matrices?

Comment: You can write it yourself utilizing `sample(c(0, 1), nrow(iris), replace = TRUE, prob = c(0.3, 0.7))`, but you can also take advantage of functionality in the caret package: https://topepo.github.io/caret/data-splitting.html